# options that can be used in if condition check

Tags: bash-scripting

if [ -z "$1" -o -z "$2" ] - Here i know that -z option is used to check for zero length string but why we are using -o option along with -z.

And also tell me any suitable link to study about those options

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

-o  simply stands for OR. The expression is true if one of the strings had a zero length. 
Have a look at table 7.2 on http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Answer (score 0):

The "[" is an alias to the **test** bash builtin.

```
$ test 1 -gt 2
$ echo $?
1
```

is equivalent to

```
$ [ 1 -gt 2 ]
$ echo $?
1
```

You can see the relative man page for further options.

```
man test
```

or [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-bash-test/) for example